# No clean data columns available for custom fields - Erro while creating a new Custom Field

Tags: custom-field, sandbox, tasks

I am getting this error when I try to create a new custom field, in my Task object, in a sandbox org.

I should mention that I previously erased a field, to open space for this new custom field, because I have reached the limit of custom fields for this object. I don't know if this helps, but I thought mention it, as an info.

Thank you!
Endrit.

Answer (score 5):

This sometimes occurs due to an error in the sandbox copying process.

You may attempt to resolve this by creating a new custom field on the object named in the install error, then delete it and then go to the bottom of your list of custom fields to the deleted fields section and erase it.

This will update that object and should allow the install to proceed.  You may encounter another similar error, just repeat the process for the next object named.

> If you're unable to leverage the workaround above due to also
>   receiving the error upon attempting to create a custom field, a System
>   Administrator will need to log a case with Salesforce Support
>   authorizing the team to run the physical delete process outlined below
>   to resolve the error.

The "No clean data columns available" error is frequently caused by deleted custom field metadata not being properly purged from the application. If this unexpected metadata state is found to be the cause of the issue through Support's investigation they may, with a System Administrator's permission, initiate a manual physical delete process on your behalf to clean out lingering field metadata that may be causing the error message.

Referred document : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000265626&type=1

Comment: Hello, thank you but, looks like this here is the standard info that salesforce provides, but it doesn't come too much in help, in my case, since, I am not exporting, or deleting any component/custom field. I am simply trying to create a new Custom Field.

Comment: @Himanshu your link appears to be broken now. Is this the updated article where you found this information? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000265626&type=1

Comment: @RobertWatson it seems to be. I am updating link. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's a sandbox.

1. Save data that you need (from objects).
2. Go to production environment and just refresh your Sandbox. Setup -> Data Management -> Sandbox. You’ll see a list of your sandboxes. Sandboxes that you can refresh have a Refresh link next to the sandbox name.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this issue.

This issue will come if you are reaching the limits for custom field creation. Custom fields will count against deleted fields as well.

So we need to Erase them from deleted fields as well. Once those are Erased from deleted field, there is button called Purge to hard delete the Erased fields.

My issue resolved by clicking on the purge button under deleted fields.